# open_memstream with fseek to end pads buffer with zeros

Tags: c, linux, fseek

I using some C code that writes binary data to a file. In the process, it seeks around to different positions and then finally seeks to the end with `fseeko(fp, 0, SEEK_END);`.

However, in some cases, I want to work on a stream in memory instead. I use `open_memstream` for this, but seeking to the end pads the buffer with zeros and it ends up being twice as big as it should be.

An example just to demonstrate the effect of the `fseek` to the end of the stream is below. In the actual code, we also `fseek` to different parts of the stream, patching and editing bits of it, etc., as the stream is processed. Note also that writing the file at the end to the filesystem is just for demonstration to show the contents of the buffer – otherwise I wouldn't need the memory stream.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#if (defined(BSD) || __APPLE__)
#include "open_memstream.h"
#endif

int main(void) {
    FILE *stream;
    FILE *outfile;
    char *buf;
    size_t buf_len;
    int i;

    stream = open_memstream(&buf, &buf_len);

    for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        fprintf(stream, "%d\n", i);
    }

    fseeko(stream, 0, SEEK_END);

    fclose(stream);

    outfile = fopen("out.txt", "w");
    fwrite(buf, buf_len, 1, outfile);
    fclose(outfile);

    return 0;
}
```

I was testing this out on Mac OS X with [this](https://github.com/shyuep/pyhull/tree/master/src/fmemopen) implementation of `open_memstream` and it worked as I expected, but when I run this on Linux the file is twice the size with zeros at the end.

What's the best way to deal with this? I'm not sure if it's reliable to divide the buffer length by two and truncate it.

Comment: What happens if you leave out the `fseeko`?

Comment: The example works fine without it. The `fseeko` is in the example because in the actual code it seeks to different places to tweak the file's headers, footers, etc., and then jumps to the end of the stream when it's all done. Maybe I should have been clearer, but the example was just to show that seeking to the end pads the memory stream with zeros at the end.

Comment: What happens in the real code if you leave out the `fseeko` to the end and just `fclose` the stream?

Comment: If I leave it out, the buffer doesn't end up with all the data in it.

Comment: according to the available documentation, the output stream needs to be fflush(stream); after every fprint() (even though each fprint outputs a '\n'.  this is to update the buf_len variable.  otherwise, if relying on the '\n' the actual malloc/realloc allocation size will be used, which in linux is significantly larger than what was requested.

Comment: @user3629249 Interesting. But it doesn't seem to fix it in the example above. And even if I add an `fflush()` both after each `fprint()` *and* after the `fseeko()`, it still gives me the zeros at the end. The `fseeko()` seems to be the thing that throws it off.

Answer (score 0):

I've just ran into the same problem on Linux.

```
// It seams that SEEK_END does not work with open_memstream()
fseek(stream, 0, SEEK_END);
```

I've ended up doing this:

```
off_t o = ftell(stream);
/* do some things with the stream */
fseek(stream, o, SEEK_SET);
```